# How to process video files with python OpenCV faster than file frame rate?

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

I have video file that I am trying to process one frame at a time,. I tried use VideoCapture class to do reading with following type of code. The problem is that if video file is recorded at 25 frames / second, the reading happens at same pace. How to get frames as fast as my computer can decode them?

I plan to process the video stream and then store it to a file.

```
import cv2
import sys
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(sys.argv[1])
start = time.time()

counter = 0
while True:
    counter += 1;
    image = cap.read()[1]
    if counter %25 == 0:
        print "time", time.time() - start
```

Output: It prints a timestamp once every 25 frames. Notice how timestamps change almost exactly by 1 second on every line => program processes about 25 frames per second. This with video file that is 25 frames/second.

```
time 1.25219297409
time 2.25236606598
time 3.25211691856
time 4.25237703323
time 5.25236296654
time 6.25234603882
time 7.252161026
time 8.25258207321
time 9.25195503235
time 10.2523479462
```

Probably VideoCapture is the wrong API for this kind of work, but what to use instead?

Using Linux, Fedora 20, opencv-python 2.4.7 and python 2.7.5.

Comment: "The problem is that if video file is recorded at 25 frames / second, the reading happens at same pace" - you're wrong about that. it does not consider the original framerate. your code above already reads as fast as it can.

Comment: "Probably VideoCapture is the wrong API for this kind of work" - yes, that's probably true. it's just an utility to acquire images, no more.

Comment: @berak Reading speed seems to be 30fps for 30fps video, 15fps for 15 fps video  etc with plenty of CPU idle.

Comment: I am not sure what the issue here is, I have processed minutes long videos in a few seconds..

Comment: Can't reproduce - tried it with a 25 fps video and my output is `time 0.0563869476318
time 0.0995850563049
time 0.142103910446` etc

Comment: @texasflood what platform you are using? linux, windows etc?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 opencv 2.4.10

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can reproduce the behavior you describe (i.e. `cv::VideoCapture >> image` locked to the frame rate of the recorded video) if opencv is compiled **without** ffmpeg support. If I compile opencv **with** ffmpeg support, I can read images from file as fast as my computer will allow. I think that in the absence of ffmpeg, opencv uses gstreamer and essentially treats the video file like its playing back a movie.

If you are using Linux, [this link](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html) shows which packages you must install to get ffmpeg support for opencv.

Comment: I can confirm that I can indeed read from VideoCapture faster than the framerate, but I'm on OpenCV 3.0 compiled with ffmpeg.

Comment: That seems to be the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this yet, but I think it could work for video files saved on the machine with a finite length (i.e. NOT live webcams). Only foreseeable downside the algorithm "may" skip frames if it doesn't process fast enough but it will probably just not read the next frame. I think in general, VideoCapture can read slower than the FPS but can't read faster. Don't quote me on it, but its something that I think I've noticed.

Use the [VideoCapture::set()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-set) to change the FPS to something faster than the file on the computer. The CV_CAP_PROP_FPS is what you want to change.

Use the [VideoCapture::get()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-get) function to verify the fps was properly set.